# Web Browser Control Resizing?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I placed a web browser control on my form and I am trying to resize it when the window resizing. However it seems like the web browser control is locked, and even in the properties panel, if I try to change the size variables, it doesn't allow me to resize it.

Here is the code I am trying to use to resize the control programmatically:

```
webDisclaimer.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(this.Size.Width - 100, this.Size.Height - 200);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried to set the "Dock" property to "None"?